# disable closing tags in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do you disable closing tags in Notepad++?

For example, if I type `<html>`, I don't want the program to add `</html>` after I type it.  The same goes for any other tags.

I have already double checked the Preferences -> Auto-Completion, and made sure it is all unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
Settings -> Preferences -> Auto Completition -> Auto Insert
```

Uncheck the option

```
html/xml close tag
```